# Javascript function doesn't get implemented

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to automate focus settings on a webcam's webpage that i have open in firefox, i'm using an addon that executes a function on this webpage whenever is loaded. The function is changing the value of the slider that's supposed to change the focus setting of the webcam.

Problem is that focus of the webcam doesn't change unless i manually click on the slider, my function changes the slider but the actual focus doesn't change.

Here is the code for my function:

```
  var myVar = setInterval(myFunction, 1000);

function myFunction() {
  var focus_value  = document.getElementById("range_focus_distance").value;
  var min_value = "140";
  var max_value = "300";
  document.getElementById("range_focus_distance").value = focus_value-1;
  if (focus_value == min_value) {
  document.getElementById("range_focus_distance").value = max_value;
}
}
```

Here is the code of the webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="IP Webcam">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://192.168.1.6:8080/ico/favicon.png">

    <title>IP Webcam</title>

    <link href="IP%20Webcam1_files/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="IP%20Webcam1_files/ipwebcam.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="IP%20Webcam1_files/icon.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="IP%20Webcam1_files/lang.js"></script>
    <script src="IP%20Webcam1_files/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script src="IP%20Webcam1_files/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="IP%20Webcam1_files/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="IP%20Webcam1_files/ipwebcam.js"></script>
    <script src="IP%20Webcam1_files/ipwebcam_override.js"></script>
    <script src="IP%20Webcam1_files/ipwebcam_plugins.js"></script>




  </head><body>




<div id="explain_audio" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
        <h4>Why do I hear the audio 4 seconds late?</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>This happens due to browser buffering and depends on the browser used.</p>
 <p>Try these solutions:</p>
 <ul>
  <li>Use Flash renderer. It's designed for reduced lag.</li>
  <li>Use Firefox and Opus audio. Opus is the next-gen low-latency 
low-bandwidth codec audio streaming codec and Firefox does little 
buffering of it.</li>
  <li>Use VLC Media Player. In it's menu, open Media ⇨ Open Network 
Stream, enter http://your-ip:your-port/audio.wav as the URL, click "Show
 more options" and set buffering to 1 ms.</li>
</ul>
<p></p>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div id="explain_tasker" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
        <h4>Tasker events control</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm">Tasker</a>
 is an automation solution for Android smartphones. It can help you, for
 example, send an SMS or change ringer volume based on your location or 
by the schedule.</p>
 <p>IP Webcam Pro can generate Tasker events, either with web interface or with customizable UI.</p>
 <p>To configure Tasker for using IP Webcam events, create a new Profile
 using "+" button and select State ⇨ Plugin ⇨ IP Webcam as a trigger.</p>
 <p>Events generated from web interface have the same event name as the 
button text. For example, the central button generates the event named 
"5".</p>
 <p>

      </p></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div id="explain_https" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
        <h4>Warning when using HTTPS?</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Getting HTTPS warning is normal when the host is not accessed using DNS.</p>
 <p>Using HTTPS still protects from eavesdropper attacks when using insecure networks.</p>
 <p>It's safe to ignore these warnings.</p>

        <br>
        <p>Navigate to <a id="https_target"></a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->



<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->





    <div class="container" id="main_container">
      <div id="init_alert" class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;">
        <strong>Cannot get camera status!</strong> Some of the functionality might not work because of <span id="init_error"></span>.
      </div>


  <div id="warn_div" class="alert alert-warning" style="display: none;">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    <strong><span id="warn_cause">Warning cause</span></strong> <span id="warn_desc">Warning desc</span>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
     <!-- lg-5 -->
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 nopadding"><a href="javascript:window.open('settings_window.html','Settings','width=500,height=500')"> <i class="material-icons" style="color: #bbb; float:right;">open_in_new</i></a></div>
        </div>


<div class="form-group" id="focal_length_host" style="display: none;">
  <label for="range_focal_length" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Optical zoom</label>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <input id="range_focal_length" class="col-xs-12" type="range" min="0" max="0" value="0">
  </div>
  <label for="range_focal_length" id="range_focal_length_label" class="control-label col-xs-1 nopadding">1 X</label>
</div>






<div class="form-group" id="exposure_host" style="display: none;">
  <label for="range_exposure" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Exposure compensation</label>
  <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input id="range_exposure" class="col-xs-12" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="51">
  </div>
  <label for="range_exposure" id="range_exposure_label" class="control-label col-xs-2 nopadding">0</label>
</div>












<div id="modetAreasPanel" class="collapse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6"><div class="row"><button type="button" data-num="0,0" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma00">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="1,0" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma10">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="2,0" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma20">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="3,0" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma30">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="4,0" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma40">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="5,0" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma50">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="6,0" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma60">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="7,0" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma70">&nbsp;</button></div><div class="row"><button type="button" data-num="0,1" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma01">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="1,1" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma11">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="2,1" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma21">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="3,1" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma31">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="4,1" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma41">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="5,1" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma51">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="6,1" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma61">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="7,1" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma71">&nbsp;</button></div><div class="row"><button type="button" data-num="0,2" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma02">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="1,2" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma12">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="2,2" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma22">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="3,2" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma32">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="4,2" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma42">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="5,2" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma52">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="6,2" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma62">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="7,2" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma72">&nbsp;</button></div><div class="row"><button type="button" data-num="0,3" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma03">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="1,3" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma13">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="2,3" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma23">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="3,3" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma33">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="4,3" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma43">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="5,3" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma53">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="6,3" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma63">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="7,3" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma73">&nbsp;</button></div><div class="row"><button type="button" data-num="0,4" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma04">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="1,4" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma14">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="2,4" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma24">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="3,4" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma34">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="4,4" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma44">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="5,4" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma54">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="6,4" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma64">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="7,4" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma74">&nbsp;</button></div><div class="row"><button type="button" data-num="0,5" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma05">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="1,5" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma15">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="2,5" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma25">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="3,5" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma35">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="4,5" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma45">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="5,5" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma55">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="6,5" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma65">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="7,5" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma75">&nbsp;</button></div><div class="row"><button type="button" data-num="0,6" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma06">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="1,6" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma16">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="2,6" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma26">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="3,6" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma36">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="4,6" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma46">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="5,6" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma56">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="6,6" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma66">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="7,6" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma76">&nbsp;</button></div><div class="row"><button type="button" data-num="0,7" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma07">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="1,7" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma17">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="2,7" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma27">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="3,7" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma37">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="4,7" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma47">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="5,7" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma57">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="6,7" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma67">&nbsp;</button><button type="button" data-num="7,7" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-default btn-xs tbtn active" id="ma77">&nbsp;</button></div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="advSettings" class="collapse" style="height: 0px;">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="range_nightvision_gain" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Night vision gain</label>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <input id="range_nightvision_gain" class="col-xs-11" type="range" min="1" max="240" value="4">
        <div class="col-xs-1 btn btn-sm btn-default" style="padding: 0;" id="set_nvg_1">1X</div>
      </div>
    <label for="range_nightvision_gain" id="range_nightvision_gain_label" class="control-label col-xs-1 nopadding">1.00 X</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="range_nightvision_average" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Night vision exposure</label>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <input id="range_nightvision_average" class="col-xs-11" type="range" min="1" max="20" value="2">
        <div class="col-xs-1 btn btn-sm btn-default" style="padding: 0;" id="set_avg_2">2</div>
      </div>
    <label for="range_nightvision_average" id="range_nightvision_average_label" class="control-label col-xs-1 nopadding">2</label>
  </div><div id="video_size_holder" class="form-group">
  <label for="video_size_btn" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Video resolution</label>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <div class="input-group">
      <button id="video_size_btn" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">176x144 <b class="caret"></b></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-container="body" id="video_size"><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>3840x2160</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>3264x1840</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>2592x1952</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>2048x1536</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>1920x1080</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>1440x1080</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>1536x864</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>1280x960</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>1280x720</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>960x720</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>960x540</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>720x720</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>720x540</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>640x480</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>640x360</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>736x412</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>544x408</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>480x360</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>400x400</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>352x288</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>320x240</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>208x144</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>176x144</a></li></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><div id="orientation_holder" class="form-group">
  <label for="orientation_btn" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Orientation</label>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <div class="input-group">
      <button id="orientation_btn" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Landscape <b class="caret"></b></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-container="body" id="orientation"><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>Landscape</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>Portrait</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>Upside down</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>Upside down portrait</a></li></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><div id="mirror_flip_holder" class="form-group">
  <label for="mirror_flip_btn" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Mirror and flip</label>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <div class="input-group">
      <button id="mirror_flip_btn" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">None <b class="caret"></b></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-container="body" id="mirror_flip"><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>None</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>Mirror</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>Flip</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>Mirror, Flip</a></li></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><div id="photo_size_holder" class="form-group">
  <label for="photo_size_btn" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Photo resolution</label>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <div class="input-group">
      <button id="photo_size_btn" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">3840x2160 <b class="caret"></b></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-container="body" id="photo_size"><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>3968x2976</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>2976x2976</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>3840x2160</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>3280x2448</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>3264x2448</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>3264x1840</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>2448x2448</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>2592x1952</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>2048x1536</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>1920x1080</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>1440x1080</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>1536x864</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>1280x960</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>1280x720</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>960x720</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>960x540</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>720x720</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>720x540</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>640x480</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>640x360</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>736x412</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>544x408</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>480x360</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>400x400</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>352x288</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>320x240</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>208x144</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>176x144</a></li></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><div id="coloreffect_holder" class="form-group">
  <label for="coloreffect_btn" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Color effect</label>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <div class="input-group">
      <button id="coloreffect_btn" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">No effects <b class="caret"></b></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-container="body" id="coloreffect"><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>No effects</a></li></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></div>

<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#focusSettings" class="">
      Focus mode <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>

<div id="focusSettings" class="in" style="height: auto;"><div id="focusmode_holder" class="form-group">
  <label for="focusmode_btn" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Focus mode</label>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <div class="input-group">
      <button id="focusmode_btn" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Manually set <b class="caret"></b></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-container="body" id="focusmode"><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>Manually set</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>Auto, manually triggered</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>Macro, manual</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>Smooth, for recording video</a></li><li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>Aggressive, for taking photos</a></li></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><div class="form-group" id="focus_distance_host">
    <label for="range_focus_distance" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Focus distance</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <input id="range_focus_distance" class="col-xs-12" type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="578">
    </div>
    <label for="range_focus_distance" id="range_focus_distance_label" class="control-label col-xs-1 nopadding">1.74/m</label>
  </div>
</div>









      </form>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- row -->


      <hr>


    </div> <!-- /container -->






<script type="text/javascript">
  //<!--
  $(greetInit)
  //-->
</script>


</body></html>
```

Why is it that the values of the function doesn't get sent to my webcam but those clicked ones does?
How can i make this work?